# Non resolved signal has multiple sources VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fsm

i am  implementing a simple FSM using VHDL .
I came out with this code in VHDL and i got this error:'non resolved signal NS has multiple sources'.I looked deeply in the code but coudln't figure out the mistake
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
                     library ieee ;
                     use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
                     entity MeallyMachine is
                     port( 
                     x,res,clk:in std_logic;
                     z1,z2:out std_logic       
                     );

                    end MooreMachine;


                    architecture M1 of MooreMachine is
                    type state_type is(s0,s1,s2,s3);
                    signal PS,NS:state_type;

                     begin
                     ETAT:process(PS,x)
                     begin
                     case PS is
                      when  s0=>  if (x='0') then
                      NS<=s0;
                                 elsif (x='1') then
                                 NS<=s1;
                                 end if;
                     when s1=>  if (x='0') then
                      NS<=s1;
                                elsif (x='1') then
                      NS<=s2;
                                end if;  
                     when s2=>  if (x='0') then
                     NS<=s2;
                                elsif (x='1') then
                     NS<=s3;
                                 end if;
                     when s3=>  if (x='0') then
                     NS<=s3;
                                 elsif (x='1') then
                     NS<=s0;
                                 end if;
                     end case;
                   end process ETAT;
                Sortie:process(PS,x)
                  begin
                   case PS is
                      when s0=>  
                            z1<='1';
                        if (x='0') then
                            z2<='0';
                         elsif (x='1') then
                            z2<='1';
                          end if;
                      when s1=>   
                            z1<='1';
                       if (x='0') then
                            z2<='0';
                       elsif (x='1') then
                        z2<='1';
                       end if;  
                     when s2=>  z1<='0';
                      if (x='0') then
                        z2<='0';
                      elsif (x='1') then
                        z2<='1';
                      end if;
                   when s3=>   z1<='1';
                        if (x='0') then
                         z2<='0';
                        elsif (x='1') then
                         z2<='1';
                        end if;
                   end case;
                end process Sortie;
           Horloge:process(clk,res,NS)
                begin
                 if (res='0') then
                      NS<=s0;
                 elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then 
                      PS<=NS;
                 end if;
                 end process Horloge;




         end M1;
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to change `MooreMachine` to `MealyMachine` at the end of the entity and in the architecture. Might not be a problem but isn't very nice ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error message: `non resolved signal NS has multiple sources` contains also the source lines, which causes the multiple driver issue. See the full Xilinx XST synthesis report.

More over, your code has multiple copy-paste errors:

1. `entity MeallyMachine is` should be `entity MooreMachine is` because your architecture references MoorMachine
2. `NS<=s0;` should be `PS<=s0;` to solve the multiple driver problem
3. Your FSM is not a Moore FSM, because the outputs depend on current state and inputs `process(PS,x)`

Comment: Can you explain more why NS<=s0; should be PS<=s0;?

Comment: Normally, NS stands for *NextState* and PS (I don't know what P is in french) stands for *CurrentState*. So if reset `res` is active (you are using a low-active reset, which are not so common in on-chip designs) then `PS` should be set to the initial state `s0`, otherwise if a rising edge occurs, `NS` should be saved in `PS`. This is just the n-process FSM pattern. -- The multiple driver problem is cause by 2 processes *writing* on `NS`. Only one process can drive the same signal, otherwise you need a resolution function or gates/logic to solve this conflict.

Comment: Clear as water!thank you.By the way P stands for 'present'(actual in english)

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw 'Sortie' and 'Horloge' and asumed french idenfifiers :)